# Xamarin form IOS - Picker Control

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, xaml

Estoy usando el control Picker para mostrar respuestas ante una pregunta, el problema es cuando las preguntas son muy largas se muestran de la siguiente manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Abra alguna manera de aumentar el tamaño del picker para que se muestren las respuestas completas ?

esto es mi codigo:

```
 <Frame HasShadow="True" OutlineColor="Black" CornerRadius="10">
            <StackLayout>
                <Label FontSize="Small" FontAttributes="Bold" Text="8.  Para un adecuado manejo de riesgos necesitamos conocer" TextColor="#2c3e50"/>
                <Picker x:Name="picker8" Title="Seleccione su respuesta">
                    <Picker.ItemsSource>
                        <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                            <x:String>a)    Los estándares y procedimientos dispuestos para nuestra actividad</x:String>
                            <x:String>b)    Estadísticas de accidentes a nivel nacional</x:String>
                            <x:String>c)    Los peligros y riesgos a los que estamos expuestos</x:String>
                            <x:String>d)    A y C</x:String>
                        </x:Array>
                    </Picker.ItemsSource>
                </Picker>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
```